# Android Push notifications on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10

Tags: android, push-notification, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging

I have a pair applications where I use a GCMBroadcastReceiver and a GCMIntentService to listen for google cloud messaging messages and then send a notification to Android's tray via NotificationManager. Pretty standard code, as far as I know I'm not doing anything strange here.
And the code works, most all devices show my notifications (both) , each application shows a similar notification, with a different icon.
The problem is, the Galaxy Tab 10 is only showing one of them, and the other not. And I can't put my finger on what could be causing the difference. 
Specially since the code is so simple.
here is the code where I make the notification:

```
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1,
            new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class), 0);

    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.notifier_app_launcher);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setLargeIcon(bm)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_notifier)
    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
    .setNumber(number)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Also, this is how I define my receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.company.mobile.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <category android:name="com.company.mobile.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

Is it a known error of that model? Has anyone experienced this before? am I missing something in the code? All feedback is welcome.

Comment: For this part `<category android:name="com.company.mobile.app" />` is your package name different for both apps?  Other than that, I there aren't any known errors with Galaxy Tab 10 for GCM.  You should debug your receiver and see if you're getting the message.

Comment: Both apps have different package names but I'm using the right name on each manifest

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was ?

Comment: In the end we had made a mistake while specifying the package names in the android manifest. I did find out you need to use the explicit names, using just .something doesn't work in some versions